# What are new features included in Mozilla Firefox 4 Beta?

Tags: browser, firefox

I have been using older version that is 3.6.13 of Mozilla. I just want to know about new version that is 4.0 Beta & its features **from development point of view**.

Comment: Are you asking for the point of view of "developers who create web pages" or "developers who help to program Firefox itself"?

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla has a draft page (i.e. not complete but in progress) titled [Firefox 4 for developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_4_for_developers). The page includes detailed new features from the developer point of view.